# How to Correctly Escape Jinja Code on Template?

Tags: python, jinja2

How to render jinja code on template?

For instance, I have a route that need to render jinja code on the given HTML template like this:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from jinja2 import Template

@app.route('/View/Package')
def getView():
    HtmlDesc="""
    <div class="codehilite"><pre><span></span><span class="p">{{</span><span class="n">cookiecutter</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">repo_name</span><span class="p">}}</span><span class="o">/</span><span class="p">{{</span><span class="n">cookiecutter</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">repo_name</span><span class="p">}}</span><span class="o">/</span><span class="p">{{</span><span class="n">cookiecutter</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">repo_name</span><span class="p">}}</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">py</span>
    </pre></div>
    """

    return render_template('package.html', html=Template(HtmlDesc).render())
```

On the template, I tried to escape jinja code with `{% raw %}..{% endraw %}` and `{% filter escape %} .. {% endfilter %}` as documented [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-1.1/docs/build/escaping.html) but it still does not work:

```
<h1>Project Description</h1>
    <div class="project-description">   
    {% raw %}{% filter escape %}{{html|safe}}{% endfilter %}{% endraw %}
    </div>
</div>
```

With exception:

> TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '<'

I know the error is at `{{</span><span...` and `class="p">}}`, value of `HtmlDesc`, therefore I am looking for a proper way to escape these kind of characters of jinja in order to render this jinja code on template correctly. Thanks.

**Added**

What I am trying to achieve is I want the `html` and `jinja` code of `HtmlDesc` to be interpreted and render properly on web browser. In my real application, the text above is not a fixed value as in above example snippet, it reads value from text file `README` which includes inside python package and converted into HTML code. The example text above it is read from python package [cookiecutter](https://pypi.org/project/cookiecutter/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a | safe to the end of whatever you want to display. It will render it out. Make it a string too.

Inside the template you seem to be missing the `|safe` in the `{{ }}` inside the Markup

Also you have to remove the `Template()` to make sure that the whole string is escaped

Comment: in the question, I did make a `|safe` next to my `jinja` code inside the template like `{{html|safe}}`. But it still raise an exception as shown. Thanks

Comment: I meant in HtmlDesc variable after the `span class ="p"`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, it seem hard to do so because the text inside `HtmlDesc` is not a fixed value as in question. In my application, it receive value read from Text File `README` which include python package and converted into this html. That text above it read from package [cookiecutter](https://pypi.org/project/cookiecutter/). Thanks

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to render html desc as a html code or as plain text

Comment: In deed, I would like that the html code, including jinja code, inside `HtmlDesc` to be interpreted by browser and rendered it as a plain text. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the Template() call

Comment: Ah That's it :D, I get works by removing Template(), thanks very much, you may update an answer and I will accept it. Thanks so much.